# Sending Email using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, email

I am using following to send an email through `ajax`. It's not sending `name`.

```
var submitForm = function(){
                var name = jQuery('[name=name]').val();
                var email = jQuery('[name=email]').val();
                var gender = jQuery('[name=gender]').val();
$.ajax({
                    url: 'http://domainname.com/Email.php',
                    data: {name: name, email: email, phone: phone, gender: gender},
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function ( data ) {
                        $(".rhino-container").html("Dear <b>"+name+"</b> You have applied successfully, Our career counseller will get in touch with you."); 
                    }
                });

            };
```

Below is `email.php`:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $to = 'yourdomain@gmail.com';
    $from = $email;
    $subject = 'Apply Online Details from a user as below---';
    $body = "Hello Admin<br><br>
            Name: <strong>$name</strong><br>
            Email: $email<br>
            Phone: $phone<br>
            Gender: $gender<br>
                ";
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $from";
    $ok = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if($ok)
        echo '1';
    else
        echo '0';
?>
```

Comment: why don't you use id as selector jQuery('#yourID').val(); instead of name... does the same thing  but with less code and easy to understand.. (incase ur fields are not multiple)

Comment: Are you trying to send on your own computer?  And if so, do you have sendmail capabilities on your computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var submitForm = function () {
    var name = $('input[name="name"]').val();
    var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
    var phone = $('input[name="phone"]').val();
    var gender = $('input[name="gender"]').val();

    var param = {
        "name": name,
            "email": email,
            "phone": phone,
            "gender": gender
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://domainname.com/Email.php',
        data: param,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: json,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status) {
                $(".rhino-container").html("Dear <b>" + name + "</b> You have applied successfully, Our career counseller will get in touch with you.");
            } else {
                $(".rhino-container").html("Something went wrong");
            }
        }
    });

};
```

Please use this PHP for Server Side.

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $ok ? json_encode(array("status" => true)) : json_encode("status" => false));

Answer (score 0):

Each line should be separated with a LF (\n). Lines should not be larger than 70 characters. Dont use breaks.

Besides that, have you tried sending an email on your server? Straight php with no ajax? Maybe your mail is not setup correctly, atleast try it out.

Also use selectors in jQuery, I haven't seen your html, but do something like

```
var name = $('#name').val();
```

Good luck.